# How to sort name with French accents in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, localization, diacritics

I have a list of area of France and I want to sort alphabet, but the result was not as I expect

```
$str_array = array('Saint-Rémy-de-Provence', 'Saint-Savournin', 'Saint-Victoret', 'Saint-Étienne-du-Grès', 'Saintes-Maries-de-la-Mer', 'Salon-de-Provence', 'Sausset-les-Pins', 'Septèmes-les-Vallons', 'Simiane-Collongue', 'Sénas', 'Tarascon');
setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8");
sort($str_array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
var_dump($str_array);
```

Here is my result:

```
array(11) { [0]=> string(23) "Saint-Rémy-de-Provence" [1]=> string(15) "Saint-Savournin" [2]=> string(14) "Saint-Victoret" [3]=> string(23) "Saint-Étienne-du-Grès" [4]=> string(24) "Saintes-Maries-de-la-Mer" [5]=> string(17) "Salon-de-Provence" [6]=> string(16) "Sausset-les-Pins" [7]=> string(21) "Septèmes-les-Vallons" [8]=> string(17) "Simiane-Collongue" [9]=> string(6) "Sénas" [10]=> string(8) "Tarascon" }
```

But I want the result with Sénas before Simiane-Collongue

How can I sort it in PHP?

Comment: Problem #1 is that `LC_ALL` is a constant, not a string literal; so use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf8");` rather than `setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8");`

Comment: Problem #2 is that you don't check if the call to `setlocale()` actually worked or not: `Returns the new current locale, or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.` On linux platforms, you can use the `locale -a` command to find a list of supported locales

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you so much. It's work like charm

Answer (score 0):

I always use this PHP class to sort my english/french arrays:

```
$array = [
    'Zzz',
    'Xxx',
    'Éaa',
    'Aaa',
    'Eee',
    'Àaa',
];
uasort($array, 'UTF_8_french::asort');

class UTF_8_french
{
    // Everything else is sorted at the end
    static $order = '0123456789AaÀàÁáÂâÃãÄäÄäBbCcÇçDdEeÉéÈèÊêËëFfGgHhIiÌìÍíÎîÏïJjKkLlMmNnOoÒòÓóÔôÕõÖöPpQqRrSsßTtUuÙùÚúÛûÜüVvWwXxYyZz';
    static $char2order;

    static function asort($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Lazy init mapping
        if (empty(self::$char2order))
        {
            $len = mb_strlen(self::$order);

            for ($order=0; $order < $len; ++$order) {
                self::$char2order[mb_substr(self::$order, $order, 1)] = $order;
            }
        }

        $len_a = mb_strlen($a);
        $len_b = mb_strlen($b);
        $max = min($len_a, $len_b);

        for ($i=0; $i < $max; ++$i)
        {
            $char_a = mb_substr($a, $i, 1);
            $char_b = mb_substr($b, $i, 1);

            if ($char_a == $char_b) {
                continue;
            }

            $order_a = (isset(self::$char2order[$char_a])) ? self::$char2order[$char_a] : 9999;
            $order_b = (isset(self::$char2order[$char_b])) ? self::$char2order[$char_b] : 9999;

            return ($order_a < $order_b) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        return ($len_a < $len_b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```